# How to load custom css and js from my bundle to twig in symfony3?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to call css and js from

```
Project/src/Front/bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/Public/css
```

OR js file

```
Project/src/Front/bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/Public/js
```

how can i include them in a proper way?

Comment: JS & CSS need to be called from your view, not your controller.( search for {{ asset() }} twig methods. Or provide an example where you need to call them from your controller and not from your view

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding to your twig blocks, this is typical usage, like so:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
{% endblock %}
...
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('script/myJavascript.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

The above shows paths under the web folder, which is a good idea instead of your src folder. So css above is `web/css/main.css` and js path is `web/script/myJavascript.js`. That's a good way to do it. i show using `asset()` and without. You can try both to see what works best.

Comment: Thanks...this is also one of the solution

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution I have found is....

## make a hard copy of the assets in web/ directory with single command..

```
php bin/console assets:install
```

now , check your web directory where all custom css/js folder are mirrored in "bundles"

How to include??

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/bundlename/css/botstrap.css') }}"/>
```

So,It worked for me!!